# Macbook retina 15" mid-2012 with LG 38UC99-W

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm interested in buying a LG 38UC99-W monitor. I'm only wondering if my mid-2012 macbook pro 15" will support it?

MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)

Graphics:

> - NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB
> - Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

I do have a display-port cable, so I don't need to connect it via HDMI. As I read that this macbook model could be limited on this. Or am I wrong?